# Need feature information about Pentaho CTools to develop the dynamic / interactive dashboards

Tags: localization, pentaho, pentaho-ctools

We want to use the CTools for the dashboard development instead using the Dashboard Designer of Enterprise Edition as it is quite limited and CTools are more powerful.

But still we have some questions regarding few features of CTools about that we didn't get any concrete answers on the forums/blog, here they are as below:-

- How can we localize the dashboard developed using the CTools?
- How can we reuse the same dashboard for the multiple customers by passing/storing a variable in session and based on that variable we would filter the data in queries for that particular customer and also apply different styling / themes on the dashboard
- Do we have CTools available for the Pentaho 5.0 and can we use the CTools on the Pentaho 5.0 Enterprise Edition?
- How easy it would be to add the Analyzer and Interactive report on the Dashboard developed using the CTools and it works/refreshes with other components on filter change?
- How can we use other charting library like d3js or highcharts on the dashboard and bind them with the data components? Any tutorial/reference?
- is it possible to add option on the Dashboard developed using CTools so that end user can add/remove chart/report from the Dashboard same as the Dashboard of Enterprise Edition?

Answer (score 2):

For the first two, use the pentaho forums. The localization question has been asked there and we're currently redoing the CDE implementation (it's not working well at the moment). Second one, you usually use a session startup xaction to store the variable in session and then access it in CDA.

Ctools will be available for Pentaho 5 during next week (probably) - we're currently testing CDE and making sure all is working. As before, they'll work both on CE and EE.

There's an Analyzer component for CDF that you can use on your dashboards. Although there isn't one for Interactive Reporting, it's very similar to the Analyzer one, so it should be very easy to develop it.

Including other chart types means developing your custom CDE components. The CDE tutorial has a chapter on how to do that.

Finally, the add/remove feature is not there out of the box. You'll have to develop support for it.

Comment: Thanks! we will wait for the new release of CTools.

Comment: Please let us know if CTools is released for Pentaho 5.0

Comment: So currently the CDF/CDE for Pentaho EE 5.x only support Analyzer Reports ? Is the support for embedding Interactive Reports still not available ?

Comment: No, that's not available although you can try using the Report Component - that'll probably work since interactive reports using the report viewer. Haven't tested it but I think it would work.